# For loop a number to create buttons inside template literal

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object, foreach, template-literals

Getting a bit stuck with this one.

I'm looping through an object (`dataLayer.Tests`) and I'm displaying the values of my content, in a DIV.   Here's an example of how this object looks:

[image]

I'm doing this by looping through my object with `forEach`. (And in this example, I'm just console.logging my result `result3`).

The problem I'm having, is that within my `forEach`, I want to display create/display buttons, depending on what the number is in the `totalVariants` key/value.

So for example, if the `totalVariants` === 2, I want to create 2 buttons.  If it is one, I want to create 1 button.

I know I need to for loop through this particular value, but I'm not sure how to do this, within a template literal.

Here's my code.

```
dataLayer.Tests.forEach((element, index, array) => {
      let result3 = '';

      let numberOfVariants = element.totalVariants;

      if (numberOfVariants >= 1) {

        for (i = 0; i < numberOfVariants; i++) {
          console.log("The number is ", i + 1);
        }

        result3 += `
        <div class="CRO-variant-result">
          <p>Date Launched: ${element.date}</p>
          <p>Test ID: ${element.id}</p>
          <p>Test Description: ${element.name}</p>
          <p>Variant Active: ${element.variant}</p>
          <p>Total Variants: ${element.totalVariants}</p>

          ${(function () {
            for (i = 0; i < element.totalVariants; i++) {
              return `<button>${i}</button>`
            }
        })()} 
        </div>
       `
       console.log("result3", result3);

      };
    });
```

I've seen solutions which include `.map` and `object.keys`, but this doesn't seem to work/return anything.  (Probably as I just need to loop through a number and not array etc.

Any ideas/pointers, would be appreciated.

Basically, I'm not sure how to loop through a number, within a template literal and return x number of  elements.

Thanks,
Reena

Comment: Are you using Vanilla Javascript or ReactJS? :)

Comment: It looks like `totalVariants` is just an integer right?

Comment: Can you paste you dataLayer.tests object here

Comment: I'm using vanilla JS and that's right, totalVariants is just a number @Nick.  So for example, looking at the first object, it would be totalVariants: 2.  And the totalVariants: 1, for the second and third objects.

Comment: total totalVariants is a number, not an object....

Comment: Yes @epascarello, that's right it's not an object, let me update it to a for loop I was trying.

Comment: @ReenaVerma sorry, a bunch of edits to my answer but should work well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numberOfVariants` is an `number`, not an `object`, so one way you could do this is create a new incrementing array of that length (`Array.from(Array(numberOfVariants).keys())` does this nicely) and then `map` over that array as you're doing.

```js
${Array.from(Array(numberOfVariants).keys()).map(i => (
  `<button value="${i}">${i}</button>`
)).join('')}
```

I'm not quite sure what you want to appear inside the button (maybe the integer of the current number as you increment)?

Comment: This works @Nick, thank you so much!!  I was trying to achieve this with a basic for loop, but I didn't think about doing it this way.  I'll have a good ready and break this down to understand it. 

And yes I wanted the current number/index, of the loop to appear in the button, as you've done it.  :). I can make the ID of the object, appear as the button ID myself.  Thank you!!